# Could not load the default credentials? (Node.js Google Compute Engine)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-compute-engine, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to create a new vm using Nodejs client libraries of GCP, I followed the below link,
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest/VM.html#create

and below is my code

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const {auth} = require('google-auth-library');
const compute = new Compute();

var cred = "<<<credential json content as string>>>";

auth.scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute'];
auth.jsonContent = JSON.parse(cred);


const config = { 
    machineType: 'n1-standard-1', 
    disks: [ { 
        boot: true, 
        initializeParams: { sourceImage: '<<<image url>>>' } 
    } ], 
    networkInterfaces: [ { network: 'global/networks/default' } ], 
    tags: [ { items: [ 'debian-server', 'http-server' ] } ],
    auth: auth, 
};
async function main() {
    // [START gce_create_vm]
  
    async function createVM() {
      const zone = compute.zone('us-central1-c');
      const vm = zone.vm('vm-name');
      await vm.create(config).then(function(data) {
        const vm = data[0];
        const operation = data[1];
        const apiResponse = data[2];
      });

      console.log(vm);
      console.log('Virtual machine created!');
    }
    createVM().catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
   });
    // [END gce_create_vm]
}
  
main();
```

when i run this, the error I am getting is

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (D:\Click to deploy\src\c2dNodeGCP\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:155:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async GoogleAuth.getClient (D:\Click to deploy\src\c2dNodeGCP\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:487:17)
    at async GoogleAuth.authorizeRequest (D:\Click to deploy\src\c2dNodeGCP\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:528:24)
```

My scenario is to take the service account credential from string variable rather than from env var or some other thing. 
I can see that it is trying to take the default credential which is not there in my case.

I was able to achieve this in java, but here i am not able to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that due to the risk of checking this service account into your code, it is highly recommended that you *do not put it as a string in your code*. Environment variable is the best practice.

Comment: Thanks @JenPerson. I understand the concern. Consider I have 3 users and i have stored the credentials in a vault or a secure location, and based on the user i will retrieve the creds from the server and perform the operation. How can I do that and what are the options.
p.s: i dont want to store them in google storage buckets

Answer (score 3):

In order to execute your local application using your own user credentials for API access temporarily you can run:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

- You have to [install sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) into your computer, that will enable you to run the code.
- Then log in to your associated gmail account and you will be ready.
- You can check the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login), to get more information.

Another option is to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to provide authentication credentials to your application code. It should point to a file that defines the credentials.

To get this file please follow the steps:

1. Navigate to the [APIs & Services→Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?_ga=2.245422660.1971724225.1600087887-638966553.1591892739) panel in Cloud Console.
2. Select **Create credentials**, then select **API key** from the dropdown menu.
3. The **API key created** dialog box displays your newly created key.
4. You might want to copy your key and keep it secure. Unless you are using a testing key that you intend to delete later.
5. Put the *.json file you just downloaded in a directory of your choosing.
6. This directory must be private (you can't let anyone get access to this), but accessible to your web server code.
   You can write your own code to pass the service account key to the client library or set  the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the path of the JSON file downloaded.

I have found the following [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/auth/auth.js) that explains how you can authenticate to Google Cloud Platform APIs using the Google Cloud Client Libraries.

```
/**
 * Demonstrates how to authenticate to Google Cloud Platform APIs using the
 * Google Cloud Client Libraries.
 */

'use strict';

const authCloudImplicit = async () => {
  // [START auth_cloud_implicit]
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library.
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Instantiates a client. If you don't specify credentials when constructing
  // the client, the client library will look for credentials in the
  // environment.
  const storage = new Storage();
  // Makes an authenticated API request.
  async function listBuckets() {
    try {
      const results = await storage.getBuckets();

      const [buckets] = results;

      console.log('Buckets:');
      buckets.forEach((bucket) => {
        console.log(bucket.name);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    }
  }
  listBuckets();
  // [END auth_cloud_implicit]
};

const authCloudExplicit = async ({projectId, keyFilename}) => {
  // [START auth_cloud_explicit]
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library.
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Instantiates a client. Explicitly use service account credentials by
  // specifying the private key file. All clients in google-cloud-node have this
  // helper, see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/blob/master/docs/authentication.md
  // const projectId = 'project-id'
  // const keyFilename = '/path/to/keyfile.json'
  const storage = new Storage({projectId, keyFilename});

  // Makes an authenticated API request.
  async function listBuckets() {
    try {
      const [buckets] = await storage.getBuckets();

      console.log('Buckets:');
      buckets.forEach((bucket) => {
        console.log(bucket.name);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    }
  }
  listBuckets();
  // [END auth_cloud_explicit]
};

const cli = require(`yargs`)
  .demand(1)
  .command(
    `auth-cloud-implicit`,
    `Loads credentials implicitly.`,
    {},
    authCloudImplicit
  )
  .command(
    `auth-cloud-explicit`,
    `Loads credentials explicitly.`,
    {
      projectId: {
        alias: 'p',
        default: process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT,
      },
      keyFilename: {
        alias: 'k',
        default: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
      },
    },
    authCloudExplicit
  )
  .example(`node $0 implicit`, `Loads credentials implicitly.`)
  .example(`node $0 explicit`, `Loads credentials explicitly.`)
  .wrap(120)
  .recommendCommands()
  .epilogue(
    `For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication`
  )
  .help()
  .strict();

if (module === require.main) {
  cli.parse(process.argv.slice(2));
}
```

You could obtain more information about this in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code), also you can take a look at this other guide for [Getting started with authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable).

#### Edit 1

To load your credentials from a local file you can use something like:

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute({
  projectId: 'your-project-id',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});
```

You can check this [link](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest/Compute.html#Compute-examples) for more examples and information.
This other [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#loading_credentials_from_a_file) contains another example that could be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just to know, is there any way to use the credentials without storing them in the storage buckets.

Comment: It is not necessary, as long as you do the authentication first as I mentioned in the first workaround, with your own user credentials for API access temporarily.

Comment: Hi @Jose, I have updated my scenario above, kindly take a look at that

Comment: @smootherbug I have updated my original answer, please check the last edit.

Comment: GoogleAuth {
  checkIsGCE: undefined,
  jsonContent: null,
  cachedCredential: null,
  _cachedProjectId: 'proj-id',
  keyFilename: '<<file.json>>',
  scopes: [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute' ],
  clientOptions: undefined
}
In this key file, name is working fine, but when I try to pass scopes or jsonContent it is not taking them. Does it work that way only, or am I missing something

Comment: Just to make sure we didn't miss anything: Does your Service account JSON key is called "file.json" or was your last Error message posted like that to avoid posting your actual project/JSON file? Do you see the same Error message when using absolute paths?